# sql query to average, after grouping by date part of millisecond

Tags: java, android, sqlite

In my android application, I am using sqlite to store rows of data. More than one rows would be there per day, and on each row there is a datetime stored in milliseconds too.

e.g.

```
millis, col1, col2, num
xxxx,   abc,  xyz,  24
xxxx,   abc,  xyz,  24
xxxx,   abc,  xyz,  24
xxxx,   abc,  xyz,  24
```

Can I have a query which can group the millis column by day(that is 24th, 25th, 26th etc.), and give my average of the num col?

e.g. output:

```
    Date         avg
    2013-11-08   20
    2013-11-07   24
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite's [Unix Time format](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime) is in seconds, you have to divide by 1000 first.
Then you can use one of the [date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to get the date portion of the timestamp:

```sql
SELECT DATE(millis / 1000, 'unixepoch') AS Date,
       AVG(num) AS avg
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Date
```

Comment: This works!  Thanks! Saved me slicing and dicing in java code.

Answer (score -1):

Use the from_unixtime to convert your milliseconds to a date and then wrap that value into the DATE() function to keep only the date part ignoring hours, minutes and seconds.

The rest of the query is trivial.

```
  SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(millis)) AS date,
         AVG(num) AS average
    FROM table_name
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: This looked exactly what I need, but it seems FROM_UNIXTIME is not a sqlite command